# PERL CGI::Ajax Passing Database Recordset in Array

Tags: arrays, perl, cgi, ms-access-2007

Note: Those who would down vote(as question uses PERL CGI tags), go on, but please give me some hint or answer.

Hi,

On testing basis, I am making a webpage using Perl CGI::Ajax.
It has following code

```
<input id="q" type="text" size="15" name="query" value="" /></br>        
<input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="exported_func( ['q'], ['content'] );">
```

So when user enters some value in textbox and clicks, a perl ajax function goes in Ms-access   database and returns record similar to query text.
After trying numerous attempts, I want to ask:
 1. How do I print database record directly to content div.
 2. If not, how can I collect database records in array and print them in content.

```
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $pjx = new CGI::Ajax( 'exported_func' => \&perl_func );
print $pjx->build_html( $cgi, \&Show_HTML);

sub perl_func 
{
#my $input = shift; # doing database action thereafter
my @vararray = qw(abcd); # how do I store query returned database records
push @vararray,'s'; # this is demo code for testing array method, which failed.
return @vararray;
#my table = document.getElementById("content"); # is this kind of thing possible
#table.innerText = "Hello"; 
}
```

Above is my trial code, for array method, but it failed with push. Using above code, content div displayed only abcd but no s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick="exported_func( ['q'], ['content'] );` only specifies a single output div, so the first value ("abcd") returned from your Perl code is placed in that div and any additional values ("s") are discarded.  If you want to display multiple returned values, you basically have 3 options:

1) Specify multiple output divs.  e.g., `onclick="exported_func( ['q'], ['content1', 'content2', 'content3'] );`  Note that this option, while the simplest, will still lose data if more values are returned than you have output divs, so it's probably best to only use it if your Perl will be returning a fixed number of data values.

2) Write a javascript function which receives all returned values and puts them in their proper places on the page, possibly combining/formatting them first.  e.g., `onclick="exported_func( ['q'], [js_display_function] );` and, elsewhere in the page, `function js_display_function() { ... }`

3) Combine all of your returned values into a single string of HTML in the Perl code before returning it.  e.g., `return '<ul>' . join("\n", map { "<li>$_</li>" } @vararray) . '</ul>';`

Comment: Thanks Dave! for clear structured answer, would be testing it, as soon as I go home.

Comment: It worked, and your information (and way of writing it) about this problem, was really helpful.